# How to talk about completing a series?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, word-usage

I was wondering how to convey  "today I've completed reading a manga series" or "I've completed watching a TV series". Does "Verb(ます stem)+終わる" sound wrong? Should I use "てしまう"?

Also, how can I say that a series is completed? Meaning that all the volumes or episodes have been released and are now available. I thought about "○○シリーズが終わった" but I doubt it sounds natural.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the JLSE! We have rules (described [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)) requiring evidence of prior research, especially for translation-related questions. It looks like you've done that for the transitive "complete" like in "I've completed reading a manga series...", but it would help if you could fill in whatever candidates you found for the intransitive "complete" like in "a series is completed".

Comment: @Mindful thank you! Before posting I looked up the second part here, on Google and on jisho, but I didn't find any satisfying word. Everything felt wrong. If it were me I'd say "○○シリーズが終わった" but I doubt it's right... I'll add it to the main post anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your completing enjoying any piece of work (not limited to series), you can simply say [verb]-終わる／終える or 全部 [verb]-る. Verbs are different according to medium, so 読む for books, 見る (formally 視聴する) for audiovisual (TV, video...), and 聞く for audio (songs, radio...). ～しまう indeed partially covers such a usage but not easy to use in this situation.

> この小説を読み終わった *I finished reading this novel.*
> アニメを13話全部見た *I completed watching (all) 13 episodes of an anime.*

There are, however, also a few fancier and terser words frequently used: 読了【どくりょう】（する） and 読破【どくは】（する） for completing books, especially the latter carries a nuance that you have accomplished a great goal. Anime fans have a funny figure of speech 完走【かんそう】（する） for watching the whole season, which is otherwise used when finishing a marathon run or such.

For the second question "a series is completed", I think most people solely choose the verb 完結【かんけつ】する "(finish and) conclude" to describe any serial story to reach an end.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. 「○○シリーズが終わった」 is right and natural.

「てしまう」 is like "will end".

> 世界が終わってしまう。
> The world will end.